# Laptop can't boot from SSD when HDD is connected

Tags: hard-drive, boot, laptop, ssd

I've just installed a new SSD on my laptop instead of the previous HDD.

When only the SSD is connected - everything works great (I've copied the OS and data from the HDD to the SSD). But when I also connect the HDD, the laptop doesn't succeed booting from the SSD.

- I can boot from SSD if it's the only drive connected.
- The laptop did succeed in booting from the old HDD when both are connected.
- I've tried changing the boot order and also deleted the HDD from boot options, but it's still not booting.

I thought that maybe the fact that I still have partitions and OS on my HDD interrupts the SSD from booting, but it's weird cause it shouldn't affect anything (from what I know) if the HDD is not even a boot option.

Details:

- I've copied everything from the HDD to the SSD with Samsung Data Migration utility.
- It's an Asus laptop (n550jv) if that matters.
- The SSD is connected where the HDD was.
- The HDD is connected with HDD caddy instead of the CD-ROM.

Is there some boot configuration I can set? Or will I have to format my HDD and start using it fresh?

Comment: If you have same data on SSD like on HDD why don't you format the HDD?

Comment: I just prefer solving it without formatting (for my convenience), cause I see it as a last resort (easy, but last)

Comment: Try [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/).

Answer (score -1):

Can't comment, so have to provide an answer.

I have a similar situation on a Lenovo laptop. I replaced the optical drive with an SSD. The computer boots fine with a single a drive plugged into either cable location, but if two non-optical drives are plugged in at the same time it ends up in a boot loop. In Lenovo's case it's a known limitation of their BIOS.

The work around for that laptop is that there are two power buttons, one for normal power and one for the maintenance menu. I use the maintenance power button to turn the computer on, then manually select the boot drive. Starting up this way allows the laptop to boot without issue. Using the normal power button causes the boot loop. If your issue is similar hopefully you also have a similar solution available.

Hope this helps.